# .filter() on Django Unioned QuerySets gives incorrect results

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model called `Event` that has both a `start` and `stop` field, both of type `DateTimeField`. I want to filter out the Events that have null `start` and `stop` fields.

Using these two queries, I get 2 QuerySets:

```
tempset = Event.objects.filter(site__slug='test-site', owner__email='bill@email.com')
tempset2 = Event.objects.filter(site__slug='test-site', invite__slug='bill-compton')
```

I've tried to do a union like this:

```
tempset.union(tempset2)
```

as well as like this:

```
tempset = Event.objects.filter(site__slug='test-site', owner__email='bill@email.com').union(Event.objects.filter(site__slug='test-site', invite__slug='bill-compton'))
```

but when I try to filter, using this syntax:

```
filtered_query = tempset.filter(start__isnull=False, stop__isnull=False)
```

and then print out the start and stop values,

```
for thing in filtered_query:
    print(thing.start, thing.stop)
```

I get this output:

```
None None
2017-09-01 11:00:25+00:00 None
2017-09-03 11:00:00+00:00 2017-09-03 12:00:00+00:00
2017-09-06 11:00:00+00:00 2017-09-06 12:00:00+00:00
2017-09-06 11:00:54+00:00 2017-09-06 12:00:54+00:00
2017-09-06 11:00:07+00:00 2017-09-06 12:00:07+00:00
```

**Note:**

If I use the `|` character to merge the two queryset, this filtered query works fine. I was under the understanding that `.union()` would allow this merging behavior however.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Q objects. It lets you do what you need: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the query `print(filtered_query.query)`. Most likely, the filtering is not added to your QuerySet. Perhaps this ticket describes the same problem: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28519.

As I understand it, all that can be done now to filter the data before the merging (if you want to use exactly `UNION`):

```
filtered_query = (
    Event
    .objects
    .filter(site__slug='test-site', owner__email='bill@email.com', start__isnull=False, stop__isnull=False)
    .union(Event.objects.filter(site__slug='test-site', invite__slug='bill-compton', start__isnull=False, stop__isnull=False))
)
```

> If I use the | character to merge the two queryset, this filtered
>   query works fine.

`|` merge `WHERE` conditions of QuerySets to single `SELECT`, but `.union()` combines results of two queries (two `SELECT`). Compare SQL of both variants.